# Solrj API/Example for collections

Tags: solr, solrj

We are building a wrapper over Solr using SolrJ.

This wrapper will allow clients to specify a collection name and then interact with that collection for insert/update/query using SolrJ wrapper.

I have been able to do insert/update/query operations, but haven't been able to find any SolrJ API/Example to specify collection names.

Its essential to use SolrJ as clients do not want to write string manipulated Solr queries directly.

Also, we want to use collections so that every client has its own index and remains distinct from other clients' documents.

Can anyone point me to SolrJ collection example/API ?

Comment: have you had a look at [spring-data-solr](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-solr) yet? You could use `SolrTemplate` along with fluet criteria API or give `SolrCrudRepository` a try.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrServer;
import org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument;

CloudSolrServer server = new CloudSolrServer("localhost:9983");
server.setDefaultCollection("collection1");
SolrInputDocument doc = new SolrInputDocument();
doc.addField( "id", "1234");
doc.addField( "name", "A lovely summer holiday");
server.add(doc);
server.commit();
```

From Solj documentation : http://wiki.apache.org/solr/Solrj

Comment: Thanks Arun. Can I have multiple threads writing to same SolrCloud but to a different collection? I will do my experiments to verify this, but a head-start with a known answer will help me a lot.

Comment: Also, if we have concurrent writes to a SolrCloud, then is there a way to use ConcurrentUpdateSolrServer functionality along with CloudSolrServer or does CloudSolrServer handles concurrency ?

Comment: but what if we need to add change the collection on the fly every time we add a document ? Can it be done via the API or should it be done in the URL that is being posted to the CloudSolrServer ?

Answer (score 2):

For someone who is not clustering Solr (no ZooKeeper), just instantiate `SolrServer` like this:

```
SolrServer solr = new HttpSolrServer("http://localhost:8983/solr/myCollection");
```